# How to remove windows old

Tags: windows-8

I have installed windows 8 pro but I have not formatted when installing it. So there is a winddows.old folder which is about 8 gb but I can't delete it. Is there any technique to delete it ? I want to delete because my windows 8 is very slow ?
Is there any other reasons that made my computer slow ?

Answer (score 2):

Run Disk Cleanup. Select **Clean up system files**

[image]

Then you'll have an option called remove Previous Windows Installations. Select that and you're done. Sorry I don't have a screenshot because it doesn't show that option for me as I don't have a Windows.old folder.

More info can be had here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows7/How-do-I-remove-the-Windows-old-folder

Answer (score -2):

If my memory serves me correct, should you take ownership of the folder and its contents, you can then delete it from your system.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753659.aspx

Comment: You don't need to take ownership of the file because there is a tool that will delete it for you.  What horrible advice.